# Error checking attribute against 'false'

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

i use this javascript syntax for validating a checkbox...

```
 alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Chkreg").checked);
  if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Chkreg").checked == false) {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "please select the checkbox";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Chkreg").focus();
        return false;
    }
```

My alert showed me false but my if loop is not working... Any suggestion...

Comment: it returns to server side code...

Comment: btw: It's called "if statement" or something like that, not "if loop".

Comment: Works for me (on FF3.6): http://jsbin.com/exavo . What do you mean by "returns to server side code"? How can it?

Comment: Try copying the whole expression from the if including "== false", maybe the value returned is just something that serializes to "false" but is not equal to the boolean false...

Comment: @stein yes you are correct.. I just found that and made it work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your box isn't checked, I would personally write it like:

```
var box = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Chkreg");
if (!box.checked) {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "please select the checkbox";
    box.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, if your script ran when the page loaded, and maybe you hadn't checked the box before, that could possibly cause the checked variable to not be defined. Using the exclamation point checks this property using truthy / falsey technique. Something that is null or undefined will also be falsy. You usually fare better with that than checking if the property is actually equal to false.